# Entity Framework One-To-One relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, one-to-one

I have the following view

```
vw_Resources
-> ResourceId
-> Name
-> ReportsTo (maps to ResourceId)
```

and the class

```
public class Resource
{
     public int ResourceId{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public Resource ReportsTo{get;set;}
}
```

and the DbContext

```
public class MyContext
{
     public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map the ReportsTo so that the DbContext returns a Resource object. I have to do this in the following method in the DbContext class using the ModelBinder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following mapping worked

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().HasRequired(r => r.ReportsTo).WithMany().Map(r => r.MapKey("ReportsTo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your entity like this

```
public class Resource
{
     public int ResourceId{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public int? ReportsToId{get;set;}
     public Resource ReportsTo{get;set;}
     public ICollection<Resource> Reporters{get;set;}
}
```

then the mapping as

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().HasOptional(r => r.ReportsTo)
            .WithMany(r => r.Reporters)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ReportsToId);
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to to have the same entity structure that I have described above?

Comment: by using `modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().HasOptional(r => r.ReportsTo).WithOptionalDependent()`

Comment: Getting the following error "Invalid column name ReportsTo_ResourceId"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have self referencing one-to-one relation because `ResourceId` is your PK. If you make it also FK you would say that dependent `Resource` is related to the principal resource with the same `ResourceId` but it cannot be because `ResourceId` must be unique. Self referencing one-to-one relation is not possible in EF at all because EF doesn't support unique non primary keys.

Comment: ResourceId is the PK and ReportsTo is a FK.

Comment: But you cannot still use it as one-to-one because it would require you to make ReportsTo as unique which is not possible in EF.